# Fill Middle Grid Column with Slider

Tags: wpf

I have a 3 column Grid -

```
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="20" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="20" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition  Height="30"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
```

I am trying to fill the * column with a slider control - I have tried DockPanel and StackPanel - cannot get the slider width to fill that middle column. The slider is for a media element position changer that loads an .avi to a set height in xaml - so the aspect ratio is taken care of. But...Width changes to the correct ratio...the Grid size changes so I cant set a Width in xaml for the slider control.

Comment: i didn't get what you wan't exactly, post more code !

Comment: I want the 2nd column filled with a slider control

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if that is exactly what you need, because it looks so obvious to me !

```
 <Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="20" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="20" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition  Height="30"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Slider Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
</Grid>
```

that gonna fill the second column :
[image: slider]

Comment: Thanks I had to set my first column from 20 to Auto - no idea why!

Comment: what you mean? does the screenshot here represent what you were looking for ?

Comment: Thats exactly what Im looking for - but I also had to set the first column to Auto for it to work